# Retrieve a list of IDs and Values from XML using Linq

Tags: .net, xml, linq

I am developing an application in .NET. I have and XML lookup table with the following format:

```
<root>
    <item ID="1">Value 1</item>
    <item ID="2">Value 2</item>
    <item ID="3">Value 3</item>
    ...
    <item ID="n">Value n</item>
</root>
```

I would like to retrieve a list of integers with all the IDs and a list of strings with all the values.
Any help would be pretty much appreciated.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: While I liked lazyberezovsky's solution very much I'm still thinking which of the two solution I should implement. The reason is that I must provide reverse lookup functionalities as well (i.e.: Value from ID and ID from Value). The first one is already implemented in the Dictionary class. Unless I am mistaken, the second function require a few lines of code. Furthermore the lookup methods must be implemented as static. So which of the two solutions (lazyberezovsky's and jyparask's) would you adopt if you were in my shoes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to convert your items to dictionary:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml);
var items = xdoc.Root.Elements()
                .ToDictionary(i => (int)i.Attribute("ID"), i => (string)i);
```

Now all ids are keys of dictionary and values are values:

```
var ids = items.Keys;
var values = items.Values;
```

And you can quickly get value of any item:

```
string value = items[5];
```

Comment: I like it too. I never have thought something like this, though it is a very nice approach

Comment: this is the best answer.  it's clever bro!

Comment: Well, I have learned from both approaches.
Thank you jyparask and lazyberezovsky!

Answer (score 1):

Providing this is stored in an XML file:

```
XElement xe = XElement.Load(file);

List<int> Ids = new List<int>();
Ids = xe.Elements("item").Attributes("ID").Select (x => XmlConvert.ToInt32(x.Value)).Distinct().ToList();

List<string> Values = new List<string>();
Values = xe.Elements("item").Select (x => x.Value).Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to create different solution - this one does just one pass of xml, parsing values and ids:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse("<root><item ID=\"1\">Value1</item><item ID=\"2\">Value2</item><item ID=\"3\">Value3</item><item ID=\"4\">Value4</item></root>");
var IDs = new List<int>();
var Values = new List<string>();
foreach (var x in doc.Element("root").Elements("item").Select(x => new { Value = x.Value, ID = x.Attribute("ID").Value }))
  {
      IDs.Add(Convert.ToInt32(x.ID));
      Values.Add(x.Value);
  }
```

IDs

```
List<int>(4) { 1, 2, 3, 4 }
```

Values

```
List<string>(4) { "Value1", "Value2", "Value3", "Value4" }
```

Comment: You need to also provide solution for the values of the XML. The asker has requested for both list of attributes and values

Comment: When converting from Xml data you should use the [XmlConvert class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlconvert.aspx)

Comment: I'll give you +1 - you was the first, I try to create different solution and if I wouldn't be successefull I'll delete my answer

Comment: Just to have another solution - It's not "one liner", but it does just one path instead of two :)